# Attack Release Envelope Follower for Spectrum Displayer

Tags: c#, .net, signal-processing

I am designing a spectrum analyzer with C# and all audio input/output processes works corretly, but while displaying the frequency spectrum, I want the harmonics to fade in/out according to the attack and release times that I have assigned(Doing something like the attack and release parameters in BlueCat's FreqAnalyst spectrum analyzer). I looked through the post on musicdsp.com, but I couldn't implement it, I guess I didn't quite understand it either. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess the SE site [signal processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions) would be more appropriate for such a question, but even there they would need more information in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Please do not spam with any language tag you can find. Use the tag related to the language you are using. Solutions will vary widely as you tagged very different languages. Also please keep in mind that question that are open to use any language are considered as being too board for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Gerhardh actually, it wasn't my intention to write/spam those languages there to attract more attention. I thought it would symbolize that I could accept help in any of those languages. Because a hint that could be given in one of them wouldn't be that hard for me to apply it to C#.

Comment: @Gerhardh but i get and take your criticism and change the tags, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with frequencies, buffer filling process takes more time than taking samples in real time because FFT(Fast Fourier Transform) computes in blocks.

Therefore, If anyone wants to modify the signal in the frequency domain, don't forget to take the FFT size into account.

musicdsp.org version of attack and release coefficients:

```
attack_coef = exp(log(0.01)/( attack_in_ms * samplerate * 0.001));
release_coef = exp(log(0.01)/( release_in_ms * samplerate * 0.001));
```

my version of attack and release coefficients:

```
attack_coef = exp(log(0.01) * fftSize /( attack_in_ms * samplerate * 0.001));
release_coef = exp(log(0.01) * fftSize /( release_in_ms * samplerate * 0.001));
```

See: https://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/Analysis/136-envelope-follower-with-different-attack-and-release.html#id1